# Catch empty ARGS in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to check if there are any `ARGS` had been sent from the command line, using the below:

```
@show ARGS
localARGS = if findfirst(ARGS) == nothing ["arg1", "arg2"] else ARGS end
```

But got the below error:

> ERROR: LoadError: syntax: space before "[" not allowed in "nothing ["

So, I recoded it as:

```
localARGS = if findfirst(ARGS) == nothing
                    ["arg1", "arg2"]
            else
                    ARGS
            end
```

I got an error, that:

> ERROR: LoadError: TypeError: non-boolean (String) used in boolean
>   context

I also tried:

```
name = (ARGS[1] == nothing ? "arg1" : ARGS[1])
```

But got the below error:

> ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element
>   Array{String,1} at index [1]

And tried:

```
name = isdefined(:ARGS) ? ARGS[1] : "arg1"
```

But ended with below error:

> ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: isdefined: too few arguments
>   (expected 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution using [compound-expressions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/control-flow/#man-compound-expressions-1), and it looks to be more clean for me:

```
localARGS = ( if isempty(ARGS) ; ["arg1", "arg2"] ; else ARGS ; end )
```

For single ARGS, `ternary operator` can be used as:

```
name = isempty(ARGS) ? "arg1" : ARGS[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

you could simply check the length of the `ARGS` variable:

```
localARGS =
    if length(ARGS) == 0
        ["arg1", "arg2"]
    else
        ARGS
    end
@show localARGS
```

Tested in Julia 0.6.4 and 1.0.0.